# Height of the box in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like the box containing my map to have a 100% height so that it fits all screens. 
For the moment the box does not reach the bottom and does not adapt when I reduce the window

```
dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        #--------- ELEMENTS TAB "carte" --------#
        tabItem(tabName ="carte",
                fluidRow(
                  box(
                    width = 3,
                    title = "Settings",
                    status = "primary",
                    solidHeader = TRUE,
                    collapsible = TRUE,
                    useShinyalert(),br(),
                    fileInput(inputId = "zip", label = "Upload your file (.zip) :", multiple = FALSE, accept = c('.zip')), 
                    checkboxGroupInput(inputId ="indice", label ="Choose a spectral index (multiple choice possible) :", choices = c("NDVI", "NDWIGAO", "NDWIMCF", "MNDWI")),br(),
                    dateRangeInput(inputId ="dates", label = "Select the date range :", start = "", end = ""), br(),
                    textInput(inputId = "mail", label = "Enter your email address :"), br(),br(),
                    useShinyjs(),
                    extendShinyjs(text = jsResetCode),
                    div(style = "display:inline-block", actionButton("reset_button", "Refresh", icon("refresh", lib ="glyphicon"))),
                    div(style = "display:inline-block", actionButton("send", "Send now !", icon("send", lib = "glyphicon"), style = "background-color : #000000 ; color : #fff ; border-color : #717878"))                 
                  ),

                  box(
                    width = 9,
                    title = "Map",
                    status = "primary",
                    solidHeader = TRUE,
                    collapsible = FALSE,
                    height = "100%",
                    leafletOutput(outputId = "map", width="100%", height = 940)
                  )
                )
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately `height: 100%` will not work with `box` in `shinydashboard`. It is only possible via JavaScript according to this [Github Issue](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/issues/356), because the layout sizes are initiated via JavaScript.

## Solution

#### Calculate the actual window height

This consists of two parts:

- Calculating and setting the height initially (calculating the exact number of pixels that height: 100% would give.)
- Modifying it any time the user resizes the browser window.

The code sets the height of the `box` to `window height - header height - 30px (top and bottom margins)`.

e.g: If the window height is 960px, the dashboardHeader is 50px, then the height of the output element will be `960 - 50 - 30 = 880px`.

```
tags$head(tags$script('
// Define function to set height of "map" and "map_container"
setHeight = function() {
  var window_height = $(window).height();
  var header_height = $(".main-header").height();

  var boxHeight = window_height - header_height - 30;

  $("#map_container").height(boxHeight);
  $("#map").height(boxHeight - 20);
};

// Set input$box_height when the connection is established
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(event) {
  setHeight();
});

 // Refresh the box height on every window resize event    
$(window).on("resize", function(){
  setHeight();
});
```

#### Modify the UI

On the UI side, give an id or class to the box, so you can set it with the JS code. i.e: I set the id of the box to `"map_container"`.

```
box(id = "map_container",
  leafletOutput("map")
)
```

#### Full code

Using the basic `shinydashboard` example

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script('
      // Define function to set height of "map" and "map_container"
      setHeight = function() {
        var window_height = $(window).height();
        var header_height = $(".main-header").height();

        var boxHeight = window_height - header_height - 30;

        $("#map_container").height(boxHeight);
        $("#map").height(boxHeight - 20);
      };

      // Set input$box_height when the connection is established
      $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(event) {
        setHeight();
      });

      // Refresh the box height on every window resize event    
      $(window).on("resize", function(){
        setHeight();
      });
    ')),
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(id = "map_container",
        leafletOutput("map")
      ),

      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$map <- renderLeaflet( {
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      addMarkers(data = cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thank you for this complete answer. I tried to adapt it to my application but I can not put my map in this new box. There is something I don't understand.

Comment: oh I didn't change the plotOutput into leafletOutput. Thank you so much @GyD. You were very very helpful ! Do you know by any chance if i still can configure the width at 100% ?

Comment: Also, if I change the size of the window the map returns to its basic configuration making the imported shapefile disappear

Comment: You can set the width to 100%, yeah. As for the 'disappearing shapefile' I can't say much without seeing your server side code.

Comment: I posted my question here, if you want to take a look ! Thanks again : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56982652/leaflet-map-returns-to-its-original-configuration-when-i-change-the-size-of-the

Comment: @Grits I just modified my answer to address your problem, please check if it works for you.

Comment: ╬Oh boy, it works perfectly ! Thank you so much ! My app is so great now :3

Comment: I applied this method on my own Shiny app to resize boxes and images. For some reason the images show up perfect locally, but when I deploy it, nothing shows up when the screen is small.