# Leaflet map returns to its original configuration when I change the size of the window

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I configured my map to fit the size of my internet window. Unfortunately, when I change this size, my map returns to its basic configuration (setView for example), and my shapefile previously imported disappears.
Is there a way to go beyond that?

```
    # server.R

#--------- ADD PACKAGES --------#
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(shinyjs)
library(sp)
library(V8)
library(shinyalert)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(raster)

#--------- APPLICATION INSTRUCTIONS --------#
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  #--------- BOX CONTAINING THE MAP --------#
  output$ui <- renderUI( {
    req(input$box_height)

    box(height = paste0(input$box_height, "px"), width = 9,
        leafletOutput("map", height = input$box_height - 20)
    )
  })

  #--------- ADD LEAFLET MAP --------#
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      enableTileCaching() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri World Imagery", 
                options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 17), 
                tileOptions(useCache = TRUE, crossOrigin = TRUE)) %>%

      addTiles(group = "OSM", urlTemplate = "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", 
               attribution = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors', 
               options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 17), 
               tileOptions(useCache = TRUE, crossOrigin = TRUE)) %>%

      addMiniMap(toggleDisplay = T) %>%
      addScaleBar(position = 'bottomleft') %>%
      setView(lng = 97.963,lat = 20.380, zoom = 6 ) %>%
      addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("Esri World Imagery", "OSM"))
  })


  #-------- READ SHAPEFILE --------#
  #-------- SAVE IN TEMP FOLDER --------#
  #-------- CREATE A CSV --------#
  uploadShpfile <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$zip)) {
      zipFile <- input$zip
      zipPath <- substr(zipFile$datapath, 1, nchar(zipFile$datapath) - 5)
      unzip(zipFile$datapath, exdir = zipPath)
      pwd <- getwd()
      updir <- dirname(zipFile$datapath[1])
      setwd(updir)
      for (i in 1:nrow(zipFile)) {
        file.rename(zipFile$datapath[i], zipFile$name[i])
      }
      shpName <- zipFile$name[grep(zipFile$name, pattern = "*.shp")]
      shpPath <- paste(updir, shpName, sep = "/")
      setwd(updir)
      Layers <- ogrListLayers(shpPath)
      shpName <- readOGR(shpPath)
      shpName <- spTransform(shpName,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
      shapefile(shpName, paste(shpPath, Layers, "_WGS84.shp", sep = ""))
      write.table(paste(shpPath, Layers, "_WGS84.shp", sep = ""), 
                  file = "info_shp.csv", 
                  row.names = FALSE, 
                  col.names = FALSE, 
                  quote = FALSE)
      shpName
    }
  })


  #-------- ADD SHAPEFILE --------#
  observeEvent(input$zip, {
    data = uploadShpfile()
    map = leafletProxy("map")
    if (!is.null(uploadShpfile())){
      if(inherits(data, "SpatialPolygons")){
        shinyalert("Successful upload !", type = "info", timer = 2000)
        cent <- gCentroid(spgeom = uploadShpfile(), byid = FALSE)
        leafletProxy("map")%>%
          addPolygons(data = uploadShpfile(),
              stroke = TRUE,
              # color = "#00FFEC",
              # fillColor = "white",
              fillOpacity = 0.5)
      }

      if(inherits(data, "SpatialPoints")){
        shinyalert("Successful upload !", type = "info")
        cent <- gCentroid(spgeom = uploadShpfile(), byid = FALSE)
        leafletProxy("map") %>%
          addCircleMarkers(data = uploadShpfile(),
              stroke = TRUE,
              # color = "white",
              # fillColor = "#00FFEC",
              radius = 6,
              fillOpacity = 0.9)
      }
    }
  })
})


    # ui.R

#--------- ADD PACKAGES --------#
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(shinyjs)
library(sp)
library(V8)
library(shinyalert)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(raster)

#--------- USER INTERFACE --------#
shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title ="Sen2extract"),


    #--------- SIDEBAR CONFIGURATION --------#
    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Map", tabName= "carte", icon = icon("globe")),
      ),

    #--------- ELEMENTS OF THE BODY --------#
    dashboardBody(


      #--------- CONFIGURE THE HEIGHT --------#
      tags$head(tags$script('
        // Set input$box_height when the connection is established
        $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(event) {
          var window_height = $(window).height();
          var header_height = $(".main-header").height();

          var boxHeight = window_height - header_height - 30;
          Shiny.onInputChange("box_height", boxHeight);
        });

        // Refresh the box height on every window resize event    
        $(window).on("resize", function(){
          var window_height = $(this).height();
          var header_height = $(".main-header").height();

          var boxHeight = window_height - header_height - 30;
          Shiny.onInputChange("box_height", boxHeight);
        });
      ')),
      # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)


      tabItems(
        #--------- ELEMENTS TAB "carte" --------#
        tabItem(tabName ="carte",
                fluidRow(

                  box(
                    width = 3,
                    title = "Settings",
                    status = "primary",
                    solidHeader = TRUE,
                    collapsible = TRUE,
                    useShinyalert(),br(),
                    fileInput(inputId = "zip", label = "Upload your file (.zip) :", multiple = FALSE, accept = c('.zip')), 
                    checkboxGroupInput(inputId ="indice", label ="Choose a spectral index (multiple choice possible) :", choices = c("NDVI", "NDWIGAO", "NDWIMCF", "MNDWI")),br(),
                    dateRangeInput(inputId ="dates", label = "Select the date range :", start = "", end = ""), br(),
                    textInput(inputId = "mail", label = "Enter your email address :"), br(),br(),
                    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                    shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.reset = function() {window.location.reload(true)}"),
                    div(style = "display:inline-block", actionButton("reset_button", "Refresh", icon("refresh", lib ="glyphicon"))),
                    div(style = "display:inline-block", actionButton("send", "Send now !", icon("send", lib = "glyphicon"), style = "background-color : #000000 ; color : #fff ; border-color : #717878"))                 
                  ),

                  uiOutput("ui", width = "100%")
                )
        )  
      )
  )
)
```

On the first image, I imported a shapefile. If I change the size of the window (2nd image), the shapefile is no longer displayed (but we see it in the inputfile) and my map has returned to its original SetView.
[image]