# Height of the box in Shiny inside a module

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to resize the size of things depending on the size of the window of the user.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965843/height-of-the-box-in-r-shiny). I did succeed in modifying GyD's excellent answer to be able to use it with modules, see code below.
Unfortunately, I needed to keep the `tags$head(tags$script(scr))` bit as argument to the call to `dashboardBody()`. I'm a little happy this works; but I'm not so happy that I am referring to tags outside of the module that they live in. That kind of defeats the purpose of working with modules.

Is there any way that I can move the resize script to `modTestUI`, so that I control the height of `"{tabName}-container"` in each call to modTestUI?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(glue)



modTestUI <- function(tabName) {
  tabItem(
    tabName = tabName,
    fluidRow(
      box(id = NS(tabName,"container"),
          #stuff goes here
      )
    )
  )
}

scr <- '
      // Define function to set height of "container"
      setHeight = function() {
        var window_height = $(window).height();
        var header_height = $(".main-header").height();

        var boxHeight = window_height - header_height - 90;
        '
tabs <- list("test1", "test2")
tabs <- glue('$("#{tabs}-container").height(boxHeight);')        
tabs <- paste0(tabs, collapse = "")

scr <- paste0(scr, tabs, '};

      // Set input$box_height when the connection is established
      $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(event) {
        setHeight();
      });

      // Refresh the box height on every window resize event    
      $(window).on("resize", function(){
        setHeight();
      });
    ')

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Menu"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Menu"),
      menuSubItem("Test 1", tabName = "test1"),
      menuSubItem("Test 2", tabName = "test2")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script(scr)),
    tabItems(
      modTestUI("test1"),
      modTestUI("test2")
    
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  #stuff goes here
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make use of CSS class selectors and to add a class to whatever you want to resize, using `htmltools`:

```
htmltools::tagQuery(
          box(
            id = NS(tabName,"container"),
            plotlyOutput(NS(tabName,"plot"), height = '100%')
          )
        )$find(".box-body")$addClass("full-tabheight")$allTags()
```

Then we can refer to this in the script by `$(".full-tabheight").height(boxHeight);`.

So the following works for me. I added in some `plotly` objects just for fun and demonstration, and I made the box resize in one tab but not the other:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmltools)
library(plotly)


modTestUI <- function(tabName, resize) {
  tabItem(
    tabName = tabName,
    fluidRow(
      if (resize) {
        tagQuery(
          box(
            id = NS(tabName,"container"),
            plotlyOutput(NS(tabName,"plot"), height = '100%')
          )
        )$find(".box-body")$addClass("full-tabheight")$allTags()
      }
      else {
        box(
          id = NS(tabName,"container"),
          plotlyOutput(NS(tabName,"plot"), height = '100%')
        )
      }
    )
  )
}

modTestServer <- function(tabName,df) {
  moduleServer(tabName, function(input,output,session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(
        df,
        x = ~x,
        y = ~y
      )
    })
  })
}

scr <- '
      // Define function to set height of "container"
      setHeight = function() {
        var window_height = $(window).height();
        var header_height = $(".main-header").height();

        var boxHeight = window_height - header_height - 50;
        $(".full-tabheight").height(boxHeight);
      };

      // Set input$box_height when the connection is established
      $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(event) {
        setHeight();
      });

      // Refresh the box height on every window resize event    
      $(window).on("resize", function(){
        setHeight();
      });
    '

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Menu"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Menu"),
      menuSubItem("Test 1", tabName = "test1"),
      menuSubItem("Test 2", tabName = "test2")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script(scr)),
    tabItems(
      modTestUI("test1", TRUE),
      modTestUI("test2", FALSE)
    
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df1 <- data.frame(x = seq(3), y = seq(3)*2)
  df2 <- data.frame(x = seq(3)*3, y = seq(3)*4)
  modTestServer("test1",df1)
  modTestServer("test2",df2)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```